# Fazer com que valor atual seja subtraido pelo anterior

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando fazer um sistema de abastecimento, preciso que ele pega o ultimo km registrado no banco de um veiculo especifico e seja subtraído pelo novo que será inserido estou tentando fazer desse modo, porém não demonstra nenhum erro, mas não faz a subtração.
Minha Controller:

```
var teste_01 = ckm.ConsultaVeiculo(viewModel.NumCarroId);
var teste_02 = teste_01.OrderBy(a => a.Km).FirstOrDefault();
viewModel.Km = viewModel.Km - teste_02.Km;
```

E essa é minha query:

```
public IList<Veiculo> ConsultaVeiculo(int Ncarro)
    {
        string hql = "SELECT v FROM Veiculo v";
        IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
        return query.List<Veiculo>();
    }
```

Comment: Um primeiro reparo, não está a filtrar o Veiculo no query, se não usar WHERE no seu SQL irão ser retornados todos os abastecimentos, e o que obterá é sempre o ultimo e não o ultimo do Veiculo atual.

Comment: @AntónioCampos Normalmente o where eu aplico no controller, e não no SQL, mas irei implementa ele no controller e ver como irá funciona, se puder coloca a resposta de como deveria ser o where

Comment: string hql = "SELECT v FROM Veiculo v WHERE idCarro=NCarro"; Substitua o idCarro pelo nome do campo na base de dados. Quanto a filtrar no Controller na minha opinião não será muito aconselhável porque estará sempre a carregar todos os registos da tabela... com o tempo e conforme o número de registos vai crescendo  o seu programa vai perder performance.

Comment: Entendo, vou começa a implementar pelo sql, o problema é que as vezes ele interfere no funcionamento do sistema e tenho que implementa pelo controller para pode funcionar.

Comment: Dependendo do BD (Oracle , Sql Server , Postgresql etc) pode ser feito também via "analytic functions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro passo é ajustar a sua consulta:

```
public IList<Veiculo> ConsultaVeiculo(int Ncarro)
{
    string hql = "SELECT v FROM Veiculo v";
    IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("id", Ncarro); // verificar se o identificador é "id"
    return query.List<Veiculo>();
}
```

Desta maneira você pegará o veículo que deseja, em seguida na sua controller:

```
var carro = ckm.ConsultaVeiculo(viewModel.NumCarroId).FirstOrDefault(); 
viewModel.Km = viewModel.Km - carro.Km;
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que aquela parte do query.setParameter irá fazer e que parametr está puxando

Comment: o query parameter serve para pegar o carro, a consulta final seria algo assim:select * from veiculo where id = [valor do parametro]
com isto vc sabe qual é o carro e consegue pegar a KM dele e subtrair.
Sem o query parameter vc vai pegar todos os carros e irá considerar o primeiro.

Comment: Ele pegaria então o meu campo onde está selecionando o carro pelo id e iria compara?